# Как решить проблемы с e2e тестированием большого проекта на Angular (4)?

Tags: angular2

Доброго времени суток,

есть довольно крупный проект, который написан на Angular (4). Сейчас появилась задача покрыть весь проект e2e и unit тестами. Решил начать с e2e. Посмотрел все нужные зависимости и настройки, поставив рядом свежую версию через Angular Cli. Прописал простой тест, несерьезный, просто проверив работоспособность, но в итоге даже он не работает.
В директории /e2e есть 2 файла:
app.po.ts

```js
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getParagraphText() {
    return 'Welcome to app!';
  }
}
```

app.e2e-spec.ts

```js
import { AppPage } from './app.po';

describe('Project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    console.log('======================');
    console.log(page.getParagraphText());
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to app!');
  });
});
```

По сути, такой скрипт должен закончиться успехом. Но что-то идет не так. Запускаю ng e2e, проходит сборка проекта (ng serve), проходят начальные настройки, выходит сообщение: "Jasmine started". После этого открывается браузер (тестовый Google Chrome) и начинается загрузка приложения (preloader). Выводится console.log() из файла app.e2e-spec.ts и всё падает со следующими ошибками:

> E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page localhost:49152 : retries looking for angular exceeded
>
> Project App
>   ✗ should display welcome message
>   - Failed: Angular could not be found on the page localhost:49152 If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
>   Может кто сталкивался с таким?